# How to recover Bitcoin files from 2011 that were erased using the Gutmann method

Tags: wallet-recovery

Всем доброго времени суток. С 2011 года на жестком диске хранился файл блок биткойн с наградой в 50 btc. Супруга по не знанию о криптовалюте удалила несколько папок включая и папку с файлом биткойн. При этом сказала что вроде была надпись о принадлежности данного продукта корпорации и будет удалено методом Гутмана. Есть ли возможность восстановить удаленный файл? Делал откат системы windows7.Папка появилась ,но файла нету(

Google translates this as

> Good day. Since 2011, a bitcoin block file with a reward of 50 btc has been stored on the hard drive. A spouse who does not know about cryptocurrency deleted several folders including the folder with the bitcoin file. At the same time, she said that there seemed to be an inscription about the belonging of this product to the corporation and will be removed by the Gutman method. Is it possible to recover a deleted file? Did a rollback of the windows7 system. The folder appeared, but there is no file (

Answer (score 1):

Any files erased using the [Gutmann method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gutmann_method) cannot be recovered. The Gutmann method is actually overkill on modern disk drives.

At best, if empty space on the drive has not also been overwritten, you might recover fragments of data from previous versions of files or temporary files. If the files have not been used since 2011 this is extremely unlikely. The more use you make of the computer since the deletion, the less likely any recovery.

The best (and probably only) way to recover control over the money is to simply recreate the wallet using backups of the files or from the written copy of the private keys which you presumably made.